# SQL Stored Procedure - Run a SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

Here is the way I am creating my stored procedure:

```
SET @SQL = 
(SELECT ddl_script FROM TABLENAME.versions where ID = 5)
;

USE TABLENAME;
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `ddl_stored_procedure`;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `ddl_stored_procedure` ()
BEGIN

PREPARE part1 FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE part1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE part1;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

This part works fine and my stored procedure is created. Now I try to run my stored procedure with this line of code to test it:

```
CALL `DBNAME`.`ddl_stored_procedure`();
```

And I get the error message:

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'USE `xxx_landing`; CREATE TABLE `TABLE1` ( `ROW1` varchar(1), `T' at line 1
```

The code that is running, is an SQL statement inside one of my databases as longtext and looks like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE `xxx_landing` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */; 
USE `xxx_landing`; 

CREATE TABLE `TABLE1` ( 
    `ROW1` varchar(1), 
    `ROW2` varchar(20), 
    `ROW3` varchar(3) 
) 
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; 

CREATE TABLE `TABLE2` ( 
    `ROW4` varchar(2), 
    `ROW5` varchar(10), 
    `ROW6` varchar(10), 
    `ROW7` varchar(10), 
    `ROW8` varchar(10), 
    `ROW9` varchar(50) 
) 
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I do not know why the stored procedure fails to create the database, use it and create all tables. If I execute the SQL-Query manually there is no syntax error.
Can someone explain me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!